# Service Bus: Can't receive any message in first 15-20 sec, then it works

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, azure, azureservicebus

I send a guid `Id` via Service Bus. Everything works fine and my page automatically add the new `Id`. However, whenever I load the page or refresh it, I can't receive any message for a while. They are somehow disappearing from nowhere. I checked azures queue for messages but it says zero, so that means the messages somehow leaking away from my code below during that time.

The "dead-time" last about 15-20 sec, then it works perfectly fine till I re-load the page again.

Sender:

```
 public void Post(Guid id) {
            var connectionString = "X";
            var queueName = "Send";

            var client = QueueClient.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString, queueName);
            var message = new BrokeredMessage(id);    

            client.Send(message);                  
        }
```

Receiver:

```
  public string GetMessage() {
            var connectionString = "X";
            var queueName = "Send";

            var client = QueueClient.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString, queueName);
            var message = client.Receive(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));

            var getId = message?.GetBody<string>();
            if (getId == null) { return null; }                  

            message.Complete();

            return getId;
        }
```

Ajax/JQuery:

```
<script type="text/jscript">
    var url = "/Home/GetMessage";
    function getData () {
        $.get(url, function (data) {
            var div = $("<div>");
            div.html(data);
            $("#content").append(div);
            getData();
        });
    }
    getData();
</script>
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Is your code above complete? I don't understand how your `GetMessage` implementation can possibly work. `var getId = new StreamReader(string)` is not fetching anything from the message itself. Regardless, my advice would be to run your distilled send/receive code in a standalone console app, without any AJAX / web containers getting in the way. In my experience send/receive via ASB is always nearly instantaneous.

Comment: @SlavaAsipenko Oh you were correct, I accidentally picked older/incorrect code. It's corrected now. So you mean ASB wont work well as I intended to do with MVC?  It's my first time using ASB.

Comment: In principle it should work fine within MVC. Just saying it might be easier to debug it in isolation first. I don't think delays are due to ASB. Especially because it works ok until page load. There maybe inherent delays due how your views render or Web requests process. Another semi-related observation - creating queue client every time from scratch is a relatively expensive operation, though it should not take 10 seconds. Fine for prototyping but consider reusing the client in the final implementation.

Comment: I'd be interested to see a repro code as a project on GitHub or BitBucket. The way receiver is spinned up and hosted can cause delays as well.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem that sounded a lot like this, my solution was to make sure the ConnectivityMode was set to HTTPS prior to the call to QueueClient.CreateFromConnectionString(...). Your problem could be that it's trying to connect over TCP, and the 20 seconds might be due to it waiting for the TCP connection to fail before trying HTTP/HTTPS. On consecutive calls it will use HTTP/HTTPS, but it's on this initial Client Creation you feel this pain.

Try this:

```
ServiceBusEnvironment.SystemConnectivity.Mode = ConnectivityMode.Https;
var client = QueueClient.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString, queueName);
```

If it works make sure you put the code that sets the SystemConnectivity.Mode in a more thought through place, and also create your Client in some sort of a Singleton. You don't want to create new Clients all the time.